Is Jesus Christ Really a Jew or Jewish?
According to Matthew 2:23 Luke 1:4 Jesus is a Galilean from ""Nazareth"", Galilee was part of "Israel" not Judah/Judea, Galilee was a Roman province and the Tetrarchy of Herod Antipas.. Therefore, non-Jew/Judeans G2453 "Israelites" lived there, arguably during the Roman era as well..
Christ is clearly of the house of Judah, however it's also quite clear that Mary is also of the tribe of Levi(Luke 1:5, Luke 1:36), and King David was also related to Ephraim 1 Samuel 17:12, Micah 5:2-3, Ruth 1:1-2..  So, Judah, Levi, Ephraim..
So, why do Christians totally ignore Biblical Scholars and constantly claim he is a Jew?  Ask me for examples..

Since when is being of Judah/Judea a requirement for being "Jewish"?

https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g2453/kjv/tr/0-1/

That is what the word means.. G2453 -  Ἰουδαῖος Ioudaîos, ee-oo-dah'-yos; from G2448 (in the sense of G2455 as a country); """Judæan""", From Ἰούδα (G2448) (in the sense of Ἰούδας (G2455) as a country)

“Jesus and his earliest followers, evidence demonstrates, were called Israelites', Galileans' or Nazoreans' by their fellow Israelites. Israel', Israelites' were the preferred terms of self-designation among members of the house of Israel when addressing other members—not 'Ιουδαιος', Jew' or Judaism'. Modern interpreters and translators of the Bible, it is argued, should respect and follow this insider preference. 'Ιουδαιος , an outsider coinage, is best rendered Judaean', not Jew', to reflect the explicit or implied connection with Judaea.”

Jesus the Israelite Was Neither a Jew' Nor a Christian': On Correcting Misleading Nomenclature

Maybe you will listen to the Israeli Rabbinout..  "Was Moses Jewish" "Well, according to the Orthodox Rabbinout in Israel, the answer is: “Definitely not”. "This should come as no real surprise because, according to the exact same rabbinout, Abraham, Isaac, Jacob and his 12 sons were not Jewish either."  https://www.jpost.com/blogs/torah-commentaries/was-moses-jewish-438994

"Jew" can also mean "Jewish as respects to birth, origin, or religion". Jesus has two of the three, or all three depending on how you define "origin". (He was born in Bethlehem.)

You didn't read the articles, clearly.  Not really, G2453 refers to Judean, "First to the Jews/Judeans" G2453, "Salvation is of the Jews/Judeans" G2453, "Persecuted by the Jews/Judeans" G2453, King of the Jews/Judeans" G2453..  Jew/Judahite H3064, refers to descendants of Judah specifically.. The Rabbinout in Israel flatly says that Moses Abraham Isaac Jacob Israel and his 12 sons weren't "Jewish" either..  That is because "Judaism" is Babylonian Talmud, not the faith of the Hebrew Israelites, most of which were never Jews in any way..  You are 100% wrong, read the articles..
